# Performance difference between two EBS volumes mounted to the same EC2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, performance-testing

I'm trying to do some very basic performance tests on EC2 with EBS.
I have created a **m3.large** instance with 2 **EBS volumes:**

```
root@ip-172-31-37-37:~# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   8G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
xvdb    202:16   0  30G  0 disk /mnt
xvdc    202:32   0  30G  0 disk /data
```

Than, I'm running a simple write disk test with dd. One volume is 3x better than the other.

```
root@ip-172-31-37-37:~# time sh -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/tmp1 bs=4k count=800000 && sync"
800000+0 records in
800000+0 records out
3276800000 bytes (3.3 GB) copied, 13.9361 s, 235 MB/s

real    0m27.571s
user    0m0.073s
sys 0m4.695s
root@ip-172-31-37-37:~# time sh -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=/data/tmp1 bs=4k count=800000 && sync"
800000+0 records in
800000+0 records out
3276800000 bytes (3.3 GB) copied, 39.5834 s, 82.8 MB/s

real    0m40.203s
user    0m0.086s
sys 0m3.347s
root@ip-172-31-37-37:~#
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Are the EBS volumes both SSD or both magnetic? Is the test repeatable? Were the tests run separately, or did you start onr, then the other, while the first was still running? Are the volumes the same age, approximately? Did you warm the volumes before formatting the filesystems? What happens if you add a third volume, and compare it?

Comment: After further investigation I found out that the EBS volumes had different formatting. Thanks!